# Trying to output value of radio buttons in table list

Tags: javascript, html

so I'm trying to output the value from radio buttons into a table, but no matter what I pick it just says 0, and then goes away very quickly. I want the results to stay up but kind of as a vertical list so it would look something like: 0 1 2 1, etc.

```html
function display()
{
    document.getElementById("displayarea").innerHTML = document.getElementById("dis1").value; 
    document.getElementById("dis1").value = "0";
    document.getElementById("displayarea1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("som1").value; 
    document.getElementById("som1").value = "1";
    document.getElementById("displayarea").innerHTML = document.getElementById("stron1").value; 
    document.getElementById("stron1").value = "2";
  }
```

So this is just some of the script because it's very long, I'm sure there's an easier way but I'm new to JavaScript. Each radio button is either dis, som, or stron ranging from 1 to 6.

```html
 <table width="400px" align="center" border=0> 
    <tr style="background-color:#8FBC8F;">
        <td align="center"><b>Results</b></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><div id="displayarea"></div></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

This is where it outputs to, like I said it keeps saying 0 very quickly and disappearing. Like it's reading all the values as 0.

```html
 <label>I have trouble falling asleep or sleeping too much</label>
 <fieldset class="options2">
     <input type="radio" name="dis2" id="dis2" value="0"/>
     <label>Strongly disagree</label>
     <input type="radio" name="som2" id="som2" value="1"/>
     <label>Somewhat agree</label>
     <input type="radio" name="stron2" id="stron2" value="2"/>
     <label>Strongly agree</label> 
 </fieldset>
```

And here's a sample of one of the button fieldsets. I appreciate any help. My main focus is getting it to stop reading all the button fields as 0 and going away very quickly.

Sorry I left out that the buttons are in a form that runs when the submit button is clicked. `<input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" onClick="display()"/></td>`

Another edit: the entire form

```
<form id="dep" name="dep">

<fieldset id="depfield">    
<label>I've lost my enthusiasm for life</label>
    <fieldset class="options1">
        <input type="radio" name="dis1" id="dis1" value="0"/>
        <label>Strongly disagree</label>
        <input type="radio" name="som1" id="som1" value="1"/>
        <label>Somewhat agree</label>
        <input type="radio" name="stron1" id="stron1" value="2"/>
        <label>Strongly agree</label>   
    </fieldset>

  <label>I have trouble falling asleep or sleeping too much</label>
    <fieldset class="options2">
        <input type="radio" name="dis2" id="dis2" value="0"/>
        <label>Strongly disagree</label>
        <input type="radio" name="som2" id="som2" value="1"/>
        <label>Somewhat agree</label>
        <input type="radio" name="stron2" id="stron2" value="2"/>
        <label>Strongly agree</label>   
    </fieldset>

     <label>I have suicidal thoughts</label>
    <fieldset class="options3">
        <input type="radio" name="dis3" id="dis3" value="0"/>
        <label>Strongly disagree</label>
        <input type="radio" name="som3" id="som3" value="1"/>
        <label>Somewhat agree</label>
        <input type="radio" name="stron3" id="stron3" value="2"/>
        <label>Strongly agree</label>   
    </fieldset>

     <label>I tend to over-eat or eat too little</label>
    <fieldset class="options4">
        <input type="radio" name="dis4" id="dis4" value="0"/>
        <label>Strongly disagree</label>
        <input type="radio" name="som4" id="som4" value="1"/>
        <label>Somewhat agree</label>
        <input type="radio" name="stron4" id="stron4" value="2"/>
        <label>Strongly agree</label>   
    </fieldset>

     <label>I often feel very emotional and upset</label>
    <fieldset class="options5">
        <input type="radio" name="dis5" id="dis5" value="0"/>
        <label>Strongly disagree</label>
        <input type="radio" name="som5" id="som5" value="1"/>
        <label>Somewhat agree</label>
        <input type="radio" name="stron5" id="stron5" value="2"/>
        <label>Strongly agree</label>   
    </fieldset>

    <label>I don't put in as much effort as I used to</label>
    <fieldset class="options6">
        <input type="radio" name="dis6" id="dis6" value="0"/>
        <label>Strongly disagree</label>
        <input type="radio" name="som6" id="som6" value="1"/>
        <label>Somewhat agree</label>
        <input type="radio" name="stron6" id="stron6" value="2"/>
        <label>Strongly agree</label>   
    </fieldset> 
</fieldset>
<p>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" onClick="display()"/></td>
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: where is dom with `stron1`

Comment: what is the value of radiobuttons with id 'dis1', 'som1','stron1'. Please provide the HTML for those.

Comment: How is your function `display` called (executed)? With an `onclick` or something? Are your radio buttons in a `form`? "Results disappearing very quickly" sounds to me like a form that gets submitted, so the site gets reloaded / redirectet.

Comment: Yes is it with an onclick that it runs, and yes they are in a form.

Comment: There we got your problem, it's the form. Can you add your `form` and your `onclick` to the question, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem was that your `form` was submitting and therefore the site got reloaded -> all values disappeared.

To fix this, you can either change `type="submit"` of your button to `type="button"` or use `event.preventDefault()` like I did in my example.

You also can shorten your script to something like this:

```js
function display(event) { // Need "event" to access prevenDefault();
  event.preventDefault(); // This line prevents the form from submitting, so your values stay visible after clicking the button
  var radios = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]')]; // Get all your radio buttons at once
  var displayarea = document.getElementById('displayarea');

  var values = radios.map(radio => radio.value).join(' '); // Get all values of your radios and concat them in a string
  displayarea.innerText = values;
}
```

```html
<form id="dep" name="dep">

  <fieldset id="depfield">
    <label>I've lost my enthusiasm for life</label>
    <fieldset class="options1">
      <input type="radio" name="dis1" id="dis1" value="0" />
      <label>Strongly disagree</label>
      <input type="radio" name="som1" id="som1" value="1" />
      <label>Somewhat agree</label>
      <input type="radio" name="stron1" id="stron1" value="2" />
      <label>Strongly agree</label>
    </fieldset>

    <label>I have trouble falling asleep or sleeping too much</label>
    <fieldset class="options2">
      <input type="radio" name="dis2" id="dis2" value="0" />
      <label>Strongly disagree</label>
      <input type="radio" name="som2" id="som2" value="1" />
      <label>Somewhat agree</label>
      <input type="radio" name="stron2" id="stron2" value="2" />
      <label>Strongly agree</label>
    </fieldset>

    <label>I have suicidal thoughts</label>
    <fieldset class="options3">
      <input type="radio" name="dis3" id="dis3" value="0" />
      <label>Strongly disagree</label>
      <input type="radio" name="som3" id="som3" value="1" />
      <label>Somewhat agree</label>
      <input type="radio" name="stron3" id="stron3" value="2" />
      <label>Strongly agree</label>
    </fieldset>

    <label>I tend to over-eat or eat too little</label>
    <fieldset class="options4">
      <input type="radio" name="dis4" id="dis4" value="0" />
      <label>Strongly disagree</label>
      <input type="radio" name="som4" id="som4" value="1" />
      <label>Somewhat agree</label>
      <input type="radio" name="stron4" id="stron4" value="2" />
      <label>Strongly agree</label>
    </fieldset>

    <label>I often feel very emotional and upset</label>
    <fieldset class="options5">
      <input type="radio" name="dis5" id="dis5" value="0" />
      <label>Strongly disagree</label>
      <input type="radio" name="som5" id="som5" value="1" />
      <label>Somewhat agree</label>
      <input type="radio" name="stron5" id="stron5" value="2" />
      <label>Strongly agree</label>
    </fieldset>

    <label>I don't put in as much effort as I used to</label>
    <fieldset class="options6">
      <input type="radio" name="dis6" id="dis6" value="0" />
      <label>Strongly disagree</label>
      <input type="radio" name="som6" id="som6" value="1" />
      <label>Somewhat agree</label>
      <input type="radio" name="stron6" id="stron6" value="2" />
      <label>Strongly agree</label>
    </fieldset>
  </fieldset>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" onClick="display(event)" /></td> <!-- Need "event" to access preventDefault();" -->
  </p>
</form>

<table width="400px" align="center" border=0>
  <tr style="background-color:#8FBC8F;">
    <td align="center"><b>Results</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <div id="displayarea"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, but how would I get it to output the values selected and not just the assigned values of each button? it just says 012012 every time. For example if I select strongly disagree for the first three questions, the first three numbers should be 000

Comment: I got it, just had to put :checked after 'input[type=radio]

Comment: @Jackie Glad to help and nice to hear you solved your problem!

Answer (score 1):

For radio buttons, every element should have the same name.Otherwise it won't function properly

Eg:

```
<fieldset class="options2">

    <input type="radio" name="nameofradiobutton" id="dis2" value="0"/>
    <label>Strongly disagree</label>
    <input type="radio" name="nameofradiobutton" id="som2" value="1"/>
    <label>Somewhat agree</label>
    <input type="radio" name="nameofradiobutton" id="stron2" value="2"/>
    <label>Strongly agree</label>   

</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need separate id's, simply make the name property same to act them as a group. You can use `querySelectorAll()` to select all the radios, then use `map()` to get all the values. Finally `join()` them:

```js
function display(){
  var el = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]')];
  el = el.map(r => r.value).join(' ');
  document.getElementById("displayarea").textContent = el;
}
```

```html
<table width="400px" align="center" border=0> 
  <tr style="background-color:#8FBC8F;">
  <td align="center"><b>Results</b></td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
  <td align="center"><div id="displayarea"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>


<form id="dep" name="dep">

<fieldset id="depfield">    
<label>I've lost my enthusiasm for life</label>
    <fieldset class="options1">
        <input type="radio" name="dis1" id="dis1" value="0"/>
        <label>Strongly disagree</label>
        <input type="radio" name="som1" id="som1" value="1"/>
        <label>Somewhat agree</label>
        <input type="radio" name="stron1" id="stron1" value="2"/>
        <label>Strongly agree</label>   
    </fieldset>

  <label>I have trouble falling asleep or sleeping too much</label>
    <fieldset class="options2">
        <input type="radio" name="dis2" id="dis2" value="0"/>
        <label>Strongly disagree</label>
        <input type="radio" name="som2" id="som2" value="1"/>
        <label>Somewhat agree</label>
        <input type="radio" name="stron2" id="stron2" value="2"/>
        <label>Strongly agree</label>   
    </fieldset>

     <label>I have suicidal thoughts</label>
    <fieldset class="options3">
        <input type="radio" name="dis3" id="dis3" value="0"/>
        <label>Strongly disagree</label>
        <input type="radio" name="som3" id="som3" value="1"/>
        <label>Somewhat agree</label>
        <input type="radio" name="stron3" id="stron3" value="2"/>
        <label>Strongly agree</label>   
    </fieldset>

     <label>I tend to over-eat or eat too little</label>
    <fieldset class="options4">
        <input type="radio" name="dis4" id="dis4" value="0"/>
        <label>Strongly disagree</label>
        <input type="radio" name="som4" id="som4" value="1"/>
        <label>Somewhat agree</label>
        <input type="radio" name="stron4" id="stron4" value="2"/>
        <label>Strongly agree</label>   
    </fieldset>

     <label>I often feel very emotional and upset</label>
    <fieldset class="options5">
        <input type="radio" name="dis5" id="dis5" value="0"/>
        <label>Strongly disagree</label>
        <input type="radio" name="som5" id="som5" value="1"/>
        <label>Somewhat agree</label>
        <input type="radio" name="stron5" id="stron5" value="2"/>
        <label>Strongly agree</label>   
    </fieldset>

    <label>I don't put in as much effort as I used to</label>
    <fieldset class="options6">
        <input type="radio" name="dis6" id="dis6" value="0"/>
        <label>Strongly disagree</label>
        <input type="radio" name="som6" id="som6" value="1"/>
        <label>Somewhat agree</label>
        <input type="radio" name="stron6" id="stron6" value="2"/>
        <label>Strongly agree</label>   
    </fieldset> 
</fieldset>
<p>
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" onClick="display()"/>
</p>
</form>
```

If you want to get the values on change of the radio try the following:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[name=asleep]').forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener('change', display);
});

function display(){
  document.getElementById("displayarea").textContent = this.value; 
}
```

```html
<table width="400px" align="center" border=0> 
<tr style="background-color:#8FBC8F;">
<td align="center"><b>Results</b></td>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td align="center"><div id="displayarea"></div></td>
</tr>
</table>


<label>I have trouble falling asleep or sleeping too much</label>
<fieldset class="options2">
    <input type="radio" name="asleep" value="0"/>
    <label>Strongly disagree</label>
    <input type="radio" name="asleep" value="1"/>
    <label>Somewhat agree</label>
    <input type="radio" name="asleep" value="2"/>
    <label>Strongly agree</label>   
</fieldset>
```

Comment: As far as I understood your code, will the text content be not replaced on every click? He wants it to be appended, vertically

Comment: @SubhasishBhattacharjee, added that solution as well as part of the answer....thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add an onchange event to the radio buttons

```html
 <label>I have trouble falling asleep or sleeping too much</label>
 <fieldset class="options2">
     <input type="radio" name="r"  value="0" onchange="showVal(this)"/>
     <label>Strongly disagree</label>
     <input type="radio" name="r"  value="1" onchange="showVal(this)"/>
     <label>Somewhat agree</label>
     <input type="radio" name="r"  value="2" onchange="showVal(this)"/>
     <label>Strongly agree</label> 
 </fieldset>
```

And then write a javascript function to display or do whatever

```html
 function showVal(radio) {
      // possible things you may do, below are examples
       alert(radio.value);
       alert(radio.checked);
    };
```